# ggplot discrete color gradient but highlighting certain categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatter plot of time series data grouped by years.  It is currently plotted with a discrete color gradient to separate the years.  I know however that one or more years are outliers and would like to highlight the points corresponding to them.

As an example using the diamond dataset

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat,price,colour=color)) + geom_point()
```

Suppose I know color F is does not follow the same relationship and would like to highlight it on the graph.  What is the best way to do it?

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat,price,colour=color)) + geom_point() + scale_colour_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

I was thinking using a blue palette but coloring F as red, but I don't know how to do the 2nd part.  Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You get black and blue by default if you use the strategy of adding 1 to a logical vector:

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat,price,colour= 1+(color=="F") )) + geom_point()
```

Because it was numeric, we got a continuous scale (bewteen 1 and 2). To make it blue with a discrete scale (which I think looks equally strange, use `as.factor()`

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat,price,colour= as.factor(1+(color=="F") ))) +
   geom_point()  + scale_colour_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.  However I was hoping to still get a discrete scale for the other diamond colors as well.  In reality I have another constraint.  To put it in context of the data set, I don't really know how many diamond colors I have in total.  I just know I want all the diamond colors to be different shades of blue and diamond color F to be red.